# How change PHP variable in a php scripts when an anchor tag is clicked on a different page?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, search, dynamic

So what I am wanting to do have a instant search feed that displays a list of the members in my mysql DB, when the user clicks on an anchor tag what is associated with a row (li) I want to change a varible in another script to be the id of the row which was click. I will provide my scripts below

**Index.php**

```
<script>
function searchUserQ(){
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='userSearch']").val();
    console.log(searchTxt);

    $.post("includes/search.php", {searchVal:searchTxt},
        function(output){
           $("#userResults").html(output);
        });
}

$("#userResults").on("click", "a.employee", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#editId").val($(this).data("id"));
});
</script>

<h1 class="editUser">Edit User</h1>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="userSearch" id="userSearch" placeholder="Search For Employee By First Name" onkeyup="searchUserQ();" />
    <submit type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="userResults">

</div>
<form class="editUser" action="includes/uploadEmployee.php" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="editId" id="editId">
</form>
```

This file creates an instant list of search results to my index page and is where the anchor tags are built I want to have change the vars

**includes/search.php**

```
<?php


$output .= "<li><div class='employeeSearch' style=\"background: url('$photo'); width: 75px; height: 75px\"></div><h6>" . $firstName  . "</h6>" . " " .  "<h6>" . $lastName . "</h6><a href='#' class='employee' data-id='$id'>Select Employee</a></li>";

  echo $output;
```

This Files is to update the databases when everything is done, right now it only updates row 42

**includes/uploadEmployee.php**

```
 $selectedId = $_POST['editId'];

$sql = "UPDATE employees SET firstName = '$_POST[editUserFirstName]', lastName = '$_POST[editUserLastName]', password = '$_POST[editUserPW]', permission = '$permission', address = '$_POST[editUserAddress]', email = '$_POST[editUserEmail]', phone = '$_POST[editUserPhone]' WHERE id = $selectedId";
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<input type="hidden" name="editId" id="editId">
```

to the form. When you click on the anchor, it should store the ID into this input field. Then the update script can use `$_POST['editId']` to get the ID of the row that should be updated.

Your anchor can be written like this:

```
echo "<a href='#' class='employee' data-id='$id'>Select Employee</a>";
```

You can set the hidden field with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#userResults").on("click", "a.employee", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#editId").val($(this).data("id"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!!, I have it all working except setting the value within the hidden input when anchor tag is clicked. Any advice?:)

Comment: Ive updated my code in the question so it is more easy to read. This is what i have regarding setting the value of the hidden input to the id of the anchor tag:

 when i check my console the data-id's are working properly and the $_POST which gets the value from the editId input is working. I am having problems changing the value of the hidden input when an anchor tag is clicked

Comment: Since the employees are being loaded dynamically, it needs to use event delegation. I've updated the answer to show that.

Comment: Just updated the jquery to what have recently updated but I still am getting the same issues of it not changing the hidden input's value. It works if I define the value statically then use $_POST but when try to dynamically update the value I get nothing. This is the error messages showing I have now ID defined in the WHERE part of my sql


Error: UPDATE employees SET  permission = '0', address = '', email = '', phone = '' WHERE id = 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Is the click method being executed at all?

Comment: How are you submitting the `editUser` form? It doesn't have a submit button.

Comment: Doesnt seem like it, I just put an alert it and nothing happend and I just didnt put a submit in the stackover flow example, theres more fields to the actual form

Comment: Please put back the code from your original question. How do you expect future readers to understand the problem you were having if they don't see the original code?

Comment: It works now that I put it in the on document ready, Thank you so much!!!! You did an awesome job explaining the issues and how to solve them the entire time.